# htaccess: Protecting manual re-write of URL address

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to **protect single website URL** or **multiple** from being manually altered?

Example:

`www.example.com/here-is-example-url/1234/page/` - this is correct URL

`www.example.com/here-is-example` - bad URL (manually altered)
or

`www.example.com/here-is-` - bad URL (manually altered)
or

`www.example.com/here-is-example-2` - bad URL (manually altered)

At the moment I do redirect such altered addresses to homepage with last **RewriteRule**, but I rather see some solution to detect manual altering of URLs and block access for such visitor.

What **RewriteRule** or **RewriteCond** will prevent this?

here is what i have so far:

```
#redirect to canonical url if no ending slash
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/page$ $1/$2/page/ [R,L]
#redirect to canonical url if anything behind slash
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/page/(.+)$ $1/$2/page/ [R,L]
#rewrite to PHP file if visiting the canonical url
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/page/$ page.php?val1=$1&val2=$2 [L]

#redirect to Homepage url if no other rule match with missing ending slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/ [R,L]
```

In case this can't be resolved by some RewriteRule is it possible to redirect such behavior to 500 access denied?

Comment: Let's back up for a second here. What purpose would it serve to make these URLs generate errors? (Is there some reason you specifically *want* to tell these users to go away?)

Comment: @duskwuff I want to show 500 access denied to anyone if they manually alter the URL. So as example last condition and rule, which redirect user to homepage if missing ending slash -  how do you adjust that condition and rule to make it [F,L] -- access denied based on condition instead of redirecting to homepage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **F**orbidden flag

```
RewriteRule here-is-example$ - [F,L]
```

as you mentioned, the above rule only catches the first example.

Most people don't see HTTP status codes, you could use an ErrorDocument to display a custom error message.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /access-denied.html
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html

Be careful, because there is no way to know whether someone has the wrong URL due to a cut and paste error or deliberate probing of your site.

*This isn't something you should worry about.*

Comment: Well your answer solve only [here-is-example] case, so with no correct regex it will work just for that one example, plus how it will work on multiple pages (safe way)?